# How to integrate payment in React Native?

Tags: react-native, paypal, stripe-payments

I have made a simple React Native shopping app with CodeIgniter backend.
Then I am new to the payment integration. How to integrate payment in React-Native?
Is it possible to integrate paypal without backend? Backend is inevitable or can it be done without backend? In only frontend, such as calling payment webview.
Any reference link or help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without server-side coding, it cannot be done.

Even though it is just a web view with transaction details, we need to maintain the value as an encrypted format while sending to the service URL and receiving the response from them and this encryption should be done on the server-side.

Also for security reason, we need to maintain database in the server-side to store the basic data of the transaction to make your system trustable one. And there are a lot more other parameters.

Without these kinds of basic security implementations, payment service guys will not allow your app to live.

For paypal integration, follow this link to get some basic understanding.
[paypal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just followed this blog. "https://medium.com/zestgeek/paypal-integration-in-react-native-9d447df4fce1".  But I think this is for test integrating. How to integrate with real paypal account and transfer money?